# What size does "int" have in Microsoft documentation with respect to PInvoke?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to call [GetScrollInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583(v=vs.85).aspx) using PInvoke:

```
BOOL GetScrollInfo(
  _In_    HWND         hwnd,
  _In_    int          fnBar,
  _Inout_ LPSCROLLINFO lpsi
);
```

I'm looking for some confirmation that `int` is the correct managed type for this as specified on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getscrollinfo):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int fnBar, ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);
```

What's the correct integer size for an `int`? Is `int = int`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767161/get-the-value-of-a-scrollbars-scroll-for-a-winforms-text-box-c help?

Comment: It is a keyword in the C# language, currently and surely for a while to come it is aliased to Int32.  And yes, int to a 32-bit or 64-bit C compiler is also a 32-bit value.  Surely for a while to come.  There is no problem.

Comment: That answers the question. I guess I'll have to look elsewhere for the source of random ExecutionEngineExceptions in my application :(